# How to use sed to extract substring from a file

Tags: unix, sed, terminal

I have a file containing lines that look like:

```
./key_simple_5349431800000000000_test.txt
./key_simple_5347940900000000000_test.txt
./key_simple_5349431800000000001_test.txt
./key_simple_5347940900000000001_10-123_test.txt
./key_simple_5349431800000000002_10-123_test.txt
./key_simple_5347940900000000002_10-123_.txt
./key_simple_5349431800000000003_test.txt
./key_simple_5347940900000000003_test.txt
```

I want to execute command on this file to extract only the numbers between underscores to have an end result that looks like:

```
$sedcommand file.txt
5349431800000000000
5347940900000000000
5349431800000000001
5347940900000000001
5349431800000000002
5347940900000000002
5349431800000000003
5347940900000000003
```

What could this command be?

Comment: Use: `cut -d_ -f3 file`

Comment: Also: `grep -Eo "_[0-9]+_" file`